# Why is moment JS subtracting or adding days not working?

Tags: momentjs

I'm trying to use Moment JS and having issues adding or subtracting dates.

For example, I'm trying to sanity  check right now and have this in code:

```
let someDateString = "01/01/2000 12:00 AM";
let startMoment = moment(someDateString, "MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss A");
let futureMoment = startMoment.subtract(1, "day");
```

^ this doesn't work and when I print future and start moment, they show the same time and date.

I tried also changing stuff around so that I create a new moment instead of using startMoment:

```
let someDateString = "01/01/2000 12:00 AM";
let startMoment = moment(someDateString, "MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss A");
let futureMoment = moment(someDateString, "MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss A").subtract(1, "day");
```

But it's still not working. Am I just missing something?
Help would be greatly appreciated as I am new to this and have wracking my head for a while on why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Watch the documentation closely, substracting or adding dates forces you to specify the chrono unit. You just wrote 'day', but its either 'days' or just simply 'd'.

```
let someDateString = "01/01/2000 12:00 AM";
let startMoment = moment(someDateString, "MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss A");
let futureMoment = startMoment.subtract(1, "days");
```

will work.

Comment: It looks like it doesn't make any difference in my case, but if that was the issue, it looks like their documentation isn't consistent. Here they use "day": https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/max/